# How can I create a currencies.transfer transaction?

Tags: substrateinterface, acala

I have created a transaction by @substrate/txwrapper-orml

```typescript
import {methods as substrateMethods} from "@substrate/txwrapper-orml";

export const methods = {
    currencies: substrateMethods.currencies
};   
const metadataRpc = await rpcToLocalNode("state_getMetadata")

const registry = getNewRegistry({
    chainName: "Acala",
    specName: "aca",
    specVersion: payload.info.specVersion,
    metadataRpc
  }
);

const unsigned = methods.currencies.transfer(
  {
    amount: payload.args.amount,
    currencyId: payload.args.currencyId,
    dest: payload.args.dest
  },
  {
    address: payload.info.address,
    blockHash: payload.info.blockHash,
    blockNumber: payload.info.blockNumber,
    eraPeriod: payload.info.eraPeriod,
    genesisHash: payload.info.genesisHash,
    metadataRpc: metadataRpc,
    nonce: payload.info.nonce,
    specVersion: payload.info.specVersion,
    tip: payload.info.tip,
    transactionVersion: payload.info.transactionVersion
  },
  {
    metadataRpc,
    registry
  }
);
```

But when I call the interface with rpc request

request

```json
{
    "key": "abcdefg",
    "args": {
        "dest": "1234",
        "amount": "1.0000",
        "currencyId": "aca"
    },
    "info": {
        "adddress": "4321",
        "specVersion": "2070"
    }
}
```

there is some error info in the response

```bash
2022-06-21 19:23:06 error: createType(Call):: Call: failed decoding currencies.transfer:: Struct: failed on args: {"dest":"MultiAddress","currency_id":"{\"_enum\":{\"Token\":\"AcalaPrimitivesCurrencyTokenSymbol\",\"DexShare\":\"(AcalaPrimitivesCurrencyDexShare,AcalaPrimitivesCurrencyDexShare)\",\"Erc20\":\"H160\",\"StableAssetPoolToken\":\"u32\",\"LiquidCrowdloan\":\"u32\",\"ForeignAsset\":\"u16\"}}","amount":"Lookup57"}:: Struct: failed on dest: {"_enum":{"Id":"AccountId","Index":"Compact<AccountIndex>","Raw":"Bytes","Address32":"H256","Address20":"H160"}}:: Decoding 1234: Invalid decoded address checksum 
 Error: createType(Call):: Call: failed decoding currencies.transfer:: Struct: failed on args: {"dest":"MultiAddress","currency_id":"{\"_enum\":{\"Token\":\"AcalaPrimitivesCurrencyTokenSymbol\",\"DexShare\":\"(AcalaPrimitivesCurrencyDexShare,AcalaPrimitivesCurrencyDexShare)\",\"Erc20\":\"H160\",\"StableAssetPoolToken\":\"u32\",\"LiquidCrowdloan\":\"u32\",\"ForeignAsset\":\"u16\"}}","amount":"Lookup57"}:: Struct: failed on dest: {"_enum":{"Id":"AccountId","Index":"Compact<AccountIndex>","Raw":"Bytes","Address32":"H256","Address20":"H160"}}:: Decoding 1234: Invalid decoded address checksum
    at createTypeUnsafe (/Users/root/Desktop/work/src/blockchain-managers/aca-manager/libs/substrate-api-sidecar/node_modules/@substrate/txwrapper-core/node_modules/@polkadot/types-create/cjs/create/type.js:73:18)
    at TypeRegistry.createTypeUnsafe (/Users/root/Desktop/work/src/blockchain-managers/aca-manager/libs/substrate-api-sidecar/node_modules/@substrate/txwrapper-core/node_modules/@polkadot/types/cjs/create/registry.js:333:46)
    at extrinsicFn (/Users/root/Desktop/work/src/blockchain-managers/aca-manager/libs/substrate-api-sidecar/node_modules/@substrate/txwrapper-core/node_modules/@polkadot/types/cjs/metadata/decorate/extrinsics/createUnchecked.js:31:21)
    at defineMethod (/Users/root/Desktop/work/src/blockchain-managers/aca-manager/libs/substrate-api-sidecar/node_modules/@substrate/txwrapper-core/lib/core/method/defineMethod.js:92:20)
    at Object.transfer (/Users/root/Desktop/work/src/blockchain-managers/aca-manager/libs/substrate-api-sidecar/node_modules/@substrate/txwrapper-orml/lib/methods/currencies/transfer.js:6:46)
    at SignService.sign (/Users/root/Desktop/work/src/blockchain-managers/aca-manager/libs/substrate-api-sidecar/build/src/services/sign/SignService.js:46:53)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async SignTransactionController.signTx (/Users/root/Desktop/work/src/blockchain-managers/aca-manager/libs/substrate-api-sidecar/build/src/controllers/sign/SignTransactionController.js:15:22)
    at async /Users/root/Desktop/work/src/blockchain-managers/aca-manager/libs/substrate-api-sidecar/build/src/controllers/AbstractController.js:183:9
2022-06-21 19:23:06 error: POST /tx/sign 500 985ms
```

Please help to see the reason for the error, thank you very much.

Comment: checkout how to send a signed transaction, there are youtube videos and you can check polkadot js or subsquid docs

Comment: but error is reported before the signature is executed, and I refer to [txwrapper-orml](https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core/blob/main/packages/txwrapper-orml/src/methods/currencies/transfer.spec.ts) for the usage of transfer.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all and I have create the unsinged transaction successfully.

The 'currencyId' parameter in the rpc request should start with "Token:"

```json
{
    "key": "//1234567890",
    "args": {
        "amount": "100000000",
        "dest": "21WSTidgZsBVsXuoj18sErrUWfPwaoeQQsiYAuTVgm6gfDPc",
        "currencyId": {"Token":"ACA"}
    },
    "info": {
        "address": "21WSTidgZsBVsXuoj18sErrUWfPwaoeQQsiYAuTVgm6gfDPc",
        "blockHash": "0x3685800f72df765896d3149045fb878ffe04a348f671facf2af1571d90f9b5c6",
        "blockNumber": 3896290,
        "eraPeriod": 64,
        "genesisHash": "0xce24ecf534daea9cd46e425659ef4950a57dd29d07272b423220129c323a64b7",
        "nonce": 34,
        "specVersion": 5004,
        "tip": 0,
        "transactionVersion": 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So the root of the problem is directly in the error. The `dest: 1234` points to `Decoding 1234: Invalid decoded address checksum` which is alluding to the fact that the address is in an incorrect format. It requires a valid ss58 format address which `1234` is not.

Example of a valid address: 23M5ttkmR6KcnvsNJdmYTpLo9xfc54g8uCk55buDfiJPon69

If you have the ability I would suggest trying to run a valid transaction against an Acala dev node (setup can be found [here](https://github.com/AcalaNetwork/Acala#3-building)). You can also reference these examples we have built out in [txwrapper-core](https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core/tree/main/packages/txwrapper-examples) which don't use the orml package but they have very similar functionality and are built out to work with dev nodes.

But again, to recap, the core of the problem here is the destination address you are using to submit the transaction. Hope that helps

Comment: txwrapper-core only support balances.transfer function which can transfer native toknen  but not support other token on the blockchain.
I have referenced the examples in [txwrapper-orml](https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core/blob/main/packages/txwrapper-orml/src/methods/currencies/transfer.spec.ts) to create a transaction for currencies transfer.